# ag-grid custom theme with selectors and nested classes

Tags: sass, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to apply a rule on the headers only from the second column and futher with this rule:

```
            .ag-header-row:not:first-child .ag-header-cell .ag-cell-label-container .ag-header-cell-label {
            justify-content: right;
        }
```

but it seems like that the selector `:not:first-child` does not work properly because when I take it off the rule applies for all headers.

I guess I do something wrong but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the selectors that `:not` is excluding in parenthesis, like `:not(:first-child)` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)).

You can also try `:nth-child(n+2)`, which should have the same effect.

However, if you are trying to exclude the first *column*, you need to apply these exclusions to the column element, not its parent. `.ag-header-row:not(:first-child)` selects all the `.ag-header-row` elements that are not the first children of *their* parent; it does not select the child elements of that class.

Hard to say what this would look like without seeing your markup, but you could try `.ag-header-row *:not(:first-child)`.